# Why doesn't File browser scroll to current folder in Windows7?

Tags: windows-7

In Windows XP, when an app brought up a file browser for me to select a File or Folder, if there had been a current directory at launch, the browser would be centered on that directory. However, in Windows 7, when the file browser is launched, while it does expand the folder view to the current directory, it does not center the window on the current dir. So I always have to scroll down to where it has expanded the current dir.

Why is this? Is there any way to fix or workaround this behavior in Win 7?

Update: I guess this is a more narrow issue than I first thought. I seem to notice it when an app pops up a Browse for Folder window (e.g. kdiff3, Agent Ransack) This dialog seems to come from Windows since the usual/customized Windows Explorer RMB options are available. If I browse for a file using the standard Open dialog from one of these apps, then there are two panes and the explorer on the left one is scrolled to the current dir.

Just found that in Windows Grep, when I bring up the Browse for Folder dialog, it does scroll to the current dir. Maybe it's using a different windows API than the other apps, which works consistently on XP and Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

It does for me

Try this: open a Windows Explorer, in the top left corner select ***Organize*** -> ***Folder and search options***. From the pop up dialogue select ***Automatically expand to current folder***

Comment: I already have that optioned selected.  I guess this is a more narrow issue than I first thought. I seem to notice it when an app pops up a Browse for Folder window - this dialog seems to come from Windows since the usual/customized Windows Explorer RMB options are available.